# Get git commands list

Tags: bash, git

I would like to make an alias for every git command.

As there are many of them, I would like to get them on a list to then make a loop in my `.bashrc`.

Is there any way to get them in shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
git help -a
```

Alternatively, your git commands are listed in the `<git-core directory>`:

```
ls -1 <git-core-directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git --list-cmds=builtins,main,others
```

`man git`:

```
   --list-cmds=group[,group...]
       List commands by group. This is an internal/experimental
       option and may change or be removed in the future.
```