# Where can I find a list of all git commands and flags?

Tags: git

I'm looking to scrape all the git commands to automatically generate a wrapper api.

Where is the best source of truth for this?

I have found a list of all commands and flags here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_git_commands

I am interested in how this is generated, and if there is some kind of raw data instead of having to scrape html tags.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31262841/1725151

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `git help -a` to list all available git commands and then `git <COMMAND> -h` to list the flags for some specific command.

Comment: To help me remember, I think of the fact that `git <COMMAND> -h` is short for `git <COMMAND> -help`